# Deleting an object and creating a new one instead

Tags: php

I have a pointer to an object, which I want to release, and then create a new one.
What I tried:

```
$this->myObject = null;
$this->myObject = new myObject($newVar);
```

Should this work? Am I doing it wrong?
I tried calling `__destructor()` manually but that triggered an "unknown function" error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP does not have pointers.

But, **yes, this is fine**. You don't need to set to `null` either; the original, now-dangling object will be garbage collected just like any other object.

[Example:](http://codepad.org/z6a5xzTN)

```
<?php
class A {
   public function __construct() {
      echo "*A";
   }
   public function __destruct() {
      echo "~A";
   }
}

$o = new A;
$o = new A;

// Output: *A*A~A~A
?>
```

Comment: @Noam: Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no need to remove, unset or NULLify the property. The old object will be gone when you assign the new one if it isn't referenced anywhere else:

```
<?php

class Foo{
    public $id, $bar;
    public function __construct($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}

$a = new Foo(1);
$a->bar = new Foo(2);
$a->bar = new Foo(3);

// No trace of Foo(2)
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

Compare with this:

```
class Foo{
    public $id, $bar;
    public function __construct($id){
        $this->id = $id;
    }
}

$a = new Foo(1);
$a->bar = new Foo(2);
$b = $a->bar;
$a->bar = new Foo(3);

// Foo(2) remains because it's still referenced by $b
var_dump(get_defined_vars());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unset($this->myObject); $this->myObject = new Object($newVar);
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

First: PHP don't know any pointers, only references ;)

At all your solution should work. You overwrite the reference of `$this->myObject` with `null`. If there is no reference to the object, the object gets destroyed. You can omit the first step, because just overwriting (`$this->myObject = new myObject($newVar);`) is completely sufficient.

Just to note: If there are other references to that object, it will not get removed immediately, but the *exact* time an object gets destroyed is something, you should *never* take care about anyway. The garbage collector does a fine job :)

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want I think you have to pass by reference, not directly, otherwise variable b stores the value that was there at the time. Try:
$a = new Foo(1);
$a->bar = new Foo(2);
$b = &$a->bar; 
$a->bar = new Foo(3);